# What is the purpose of the RG10MEG Resistor in this circuit?

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image: Circuit]

What is the purpose of the RG10MEG Resistor in this circuit? Why is it there, I can't see any difference in the simulation when it's missing.
PS: U_IN = 3V DC + 1.5V sinusoidal at 1kHz

Comment: Did you consider posting this on the Electrical Engineering Stack?

Comment: Answered here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/502945/152903